# "Штуковина" - какая часть речи?

Tags: части-речи

Слово "штуковина", и его менее литературные синонимы, это какая часть речи, существительное или местоимение? По структуре скорей первое, но по семантике ближе ко второму.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Существительное. Мне кажется, что список местоимений конечный. И в этом списке такого слова нет. Хотя я понимаю Ваши сомнения, так как словом штука мы можем заменить многие существительные. Но это потому, что значение у этого существительного такое: "штука - это отдельно взятый предмет". Кроме того, мы можем определить и другие признаки существительного: женский род, первое склонение, неодушевленное, нарицательное. А штуковина - тем более существительное. У него еще и суффикс существительного.

Answer (score 2):

Штуковина -существительное, она - это  уже местоимение

Answer (score 2):

Однозначно существительное.

Comment: Раз "однозначно", то назовите, пожалуйста, хоть одно понятие или неодушевлённый предмет, который можно назвать "он" (она, оно), но нельзя назвать штуковиной?

Comment: Я не вижу связи между составом слова и "можно назвать "он" (она, оно), но нельзя назвать штуковиной". 
Здесь есть корень "штук", суффикс и окончание. Я даже не понимаю, почему вам в голову пришло, что "штуковина" вообще может быть местоимением?

Comment: А зачем вы отвечаете на вопрос, если его не поняли? Открываем определение слова местоимение (по БТС): *часть речи, к которой относятся слова, указывающие или называющие предметы или их признаки, не раскрывая их содержания, и выступающие в речи вместо слов, относящихся к существительному, прилагательному или числительному*. И ищем к какой части определения слово "штуковина" не подходит.

Comment: Я ответила на вопрос, потому что "штуковина" нельзя причислить к местоимениям. И связи с местоимением не вижу. Причем тут местоимение вообще, если это однозначно существительное? Слово "штука" - местоимение, по вашему? Есть немало существительных, которые не раскрывают содержания предметов и признаков, однако это не местоимения.

Comment: Так в вопросе про все подобные существительные и спрашивал, просто остальные менее литератуны, *фиговина*, например. Причины сомнений я вопросе озвучил, были даны другие ответы. Какой смысл писать ответ, если вы в нём не сказали ничего того, что не прозвучало в других ответах, не указали каких-то новых источниках и даже по форме он ничем не выделяется, кроме претензии на истину в последней инстанции у вас нет. Я даже плюсанул бы этот ответ, если б он был первым, но при наличии ещё двух с анологичным мнением, не вижу в нём смысла.

Comment: Марк, смысл моего ответа даже не в повторе двух предыдущих. Меня просто очень удивила сама мысль, что слово "штуковина" можно принять за местоимение, когда даже основательных предпосылок к появлению такого мнения нет. Вот вы сейчас упомянули слово "фиговина", а ведь здесь аналогичная ситуация: "фиговина" обладает признаками существительного, но его нельзя счесть местоимением. Как вам это удается - вот что меня удивляет. 
ЗЫ. Плюсанете или нет - меня это не беспокоит, поверьте.

Comment: Ясно, я понял вашу мысль (эмоцию?). Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Да, Марк, вы правы. Скорее, это даже эмоция была))). Удивление.